# (Dis)prove $\,a\mid b\,\Rightarrow\, a+b\mid b+c$

Tags: divisibility

Can someone help me here? I'm completed stuck in this simple problem.

Let a, b, c $\in \mathbb{N} $, check if the statement below is true or false:   
if   a|b then (a+b) | (b+c)

Any tips? 
What i've done so far:

If a|b, then b=a.c 
To prove that (a+b)|(b+c) there must be a j, such as (b+c) = (a+b)*j

1. (a+b) -> a+a.c
2. (b+c) -> a.c + c
3. (a+b)*j =?= (a.c+c)

Oh lord, just tried one case and found out that it is false. 
Take a = 3, b = 6, c =2

1. a|b -> b =a.c -> 6=3*2
2. (a+b) | (b+c) -> (b+c) = (a+b)*j -> 6+2=(3+6)*j -> 8=9*j 
   (there's no j in N that satifies this equation

Comment: you should tell us which triples a,b,c you have already tested. Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: press "Edit" above; you should include what you've done so far in your main post.

Comment: $a\mid b\Rightarrow \color{#c00}a\mid a+b\mid \color{#c00}{b+c}.\,$ To get a counterexample it suffices to choose $\,b,c\,$ with $\,\color{#c00}{b+c}\,$ is coprime to $\,\color{#c00}a\,$ e.g. $\,b+c = 1\,$ or $\,1+a.\,$ Once all is clear please delete the question since we already have too many answers explaining such matters. $\ \ $

Comment: Same counterexample there works here if we double $\,3\mid 6\,$ to $\,6\mid 12\,$ (to force $a\mid b).\,$ Counterexamples abound. Please check for such *before* posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried one case and found out that it is false.
Take a = 3, b = 6, c =2

a|b -> b =a.c -> 6=3*2
(a+b) | (b+c) -> (b+c) = (a+b)*j -> 6+2=(3+6)j -> 8=9j
(there's no j in N that satifies this equation

Comment: also a=b=2 and c=1